# Random number into div and then let delete divs in sequence. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So, i want to make game for my child. Have low experience in JS.

***Scenario:*** 
Have for example 4 square divs with blank bg. After refresh (or win) i want to:

Generate random numbers into div (1...4). And show them in them.

Then let player delete those divs by clicking on them, but in sequence how divs are numbered.

*For example after refresh divs have those numbers **2 3 1 4.** So, user has to have rights to delete first div numbered **1** (2 3 _ 4) and so on.*  If he clicks on **2** it get error , div stays in place, and user can try again delete right one.

It game for learning numbers. I have the begining.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid">
    <div id="Uleft"></div>
    <div id="Uright"></div>
    <div id="Dleft"></div>
    <div id="Dright"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(".grid").children( "div" ).on("click", function(){
$(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**css.css**

```
.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 430px;
}

#Uleft, #Uright, #Dleft, #Dright {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#Uright {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}

#Uleft {
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#Dleft {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

#Dright {
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

So, i guess i have use jQuery as well, but i dont know how to make it dynamic and different after refresh of page. Please help :)

http://jsfiddle.net/bNa8Z/

Comment: please elaborate more to problem, your scenario is not clear.what do you want.

Comment: It very clear. Try my code and you will undestand. I want to make a game for learning the sequence of numbers. If they are showed 4 2 1 3, kid must can delete them but in sequence 1 2 3 4.

Comment: Can you make this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bNa8Z/

Comment: @user3462947 Are you able to generate the number in the divs, if yes then how??

Comment: No, im asking for that. What i have is in jsfiddle. 
I need to add that random generation and feature to destroy div by clicking on right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you have to do. First you have to create a random array which you use `sort` and `Math.random()` to do then, you need insert the text in the squares. Find the min of the visible squares and then remove/alert depending if its the min value.

```
   // sort by random
   var rnd = [1,2,3,4].sort(function() {
     return .5 - Math.random();
   });

   // map over each div in the grid
   $('.grid div').each(function(ii, div) {
      $(div).text(rnd[ii]); // set the text to the ii'th rnd
   });

   function minVisible() {
       var min = 1e10; // a big number

       $('.grid div').each(function(ii, div) {
           // if not visible ignore
           if ($(div).css('visibility') === "hidden" ){
               return;
           }

           // if new min, store
           var curFloatValue = parseFloat($(div).text());
           console.log(curFloatValue);
           if (curFloatValue < min) {
               min = curFloatValue;
           }
       });

       return min;
   }

   $(".grid").children( "div" ).on("click", function(){
       var clickedFloatValue = parseFloat($(this).text());
       if (clickedFloatValue == minVisible()) {
          $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
       } else {
           alert("sorry little tike");
       }

   });
```

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bNa8Z/2/

Comment: Can error be shown not in alert, but over divs as text?

Comment: Nice. How is that easy to you? I want to learn JS too, to make more things like that.

Comment: One more question: how to trigger that game is over and reload or show message - "Win"?

Comment: @user3462947 - If you don't find a "new" minimum value you know the game is over, so try adding `if (minVisible() == 1e10) { alert('you win') }` at the end of the `click` callback function. Think about how you might also keep score ;)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly this is what it would look like:

```
var selected = {};

$('.grid div').each(function(idx){
    var is_done = false;
    do{
        var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
        if( selected[rand] == undefined ){
            $(this).html(rand);
            selected[rand] = 1;
            is_done = true;
        }
    }while(!is_done);
});

alert("Start the game");

var clicked = [];

$('.grid').on('click', 'div.block', function(){
    var num = $(this).html();
    if( num == clicked.length + 1 ){
        //alert(num + " is correct!");
        clicked.push(num);
        $(this).addClass("hide");
    }else{
        alert("Failed!");    
    }
    if( clicked.length == 4 ){
        alert("You Won!");   
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block" id="Uleft"></div>
    <div class="block" id="Uright"></div>
    <div class="block" id="Dleft"></div>
    <div class="block" id="Dright"></div>
</div>
```

Added CSS:

```
#Uleft, #Uright, #Dleft, #Dright {
    position:absolute;
    ...
}

#Uright {
    left:220px;
    top:0px;
    background-color: red;
}

#Uleft {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#Dleft {
    left:0px;
    top:220px;
    background-color: green;
}

#Dright {
    left:220px;
    top:220px;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

See the working version at

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fcux/3/)

You will need to re-"run" the fiddle per game.

Comment: How to make refresh page after win automatically?

Comment: location.reload(); I would add that line after the "You Won" alert.

Answer (score 0):

please try it. I think that It will help you.

```
var generated_random_number_sequesce = function(){ 
  var number_array = [];
  var number_string = '';
  var is_true = true;
  while(is_true){
    var ran_num = Math.round(1 + Math.random()*3);
    if(number_string.indexOf(ran_num) == -1 && ran_num < 5){
      number_array[number_array.length] = ran_num;
      number_string = number_string + ran_num;
      if(number_array.length == 4){is_true = false;}
   }
 }
 return number_array; 
}

var set_number_on_divs = function(){
  var number_array = generated_random_number_sequesce();
  $(".grid").children().each(function(index, element){
    $(this).attr('data-div_number' , number_array[index]);
  });
}
set_number_on_divs()

var clicked = 0;
$(".grid").children( "div" ).on("click", function(){
  clicked += 1;
  var current_div_number = $(this).attr('data-div_number');
  if( parseInt(current_div_number) == clicked){
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
  } else{
    clicked -= 1;
    alert('error');
  }
});
```